# How to create satellite layer with labels using react-leaflet-google-layer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

Trying to implement satellite view with labels on my react project using **react-leaflet** and **react-leaflet-google-layer** packages.
I can create satellite view but not able to add labels on map (city names).
Can someone guide me.

```
<ReactLeafletGoogleLayer
googleMapsAddLayers={[{ name: 'TransitLayer' }]}
type="satellite"
apiKey={GMAPS_KEY}/>
```